# Trouble matching regex that includes a dot

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python and trying to remove a specific phrase from a string and the phrase ends with a dot (.). The issue is, I understand the dot should be escaped since it is a wildcard, but it's not working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's an example without the dot:

```
import re
line = 'xx1001.89.3'
tmp = re.sub('xx1001','',line)
print tmp
.89.3
```

But, now with the dot:

```
tmp = re.sub('xx1001.','',line)
print tmp
9.3
```

So, it used the dot as wildcard. But if I try escaping it, the pattern is not found in line:

```
tmp = re.sub('xx1001\.','',line)
print tmp
xx1001.89.3
```

In all these cases, what I really seek is removing `xx1001.` which should leave just `89.3`

I'm feeling pretty confident that I'm making a noob mistake here, but just can't seem to find a solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: Well, it works fine with escape.

Comment: Works fine... are you sure there isn't other code we haven't seen that  modifies `tmp`?

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I swear it wasn't working before! How very Friday afternoon....

Comment: It works fine for me with escape or not. Python 2.7?

Comment: If your goal is to final a decimal at the end of any string, give this a try: `re.search(r'\d+\.\d+$', 'xx1001.89.3').group(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.

Anyway this should work too for a simple replacement:

```
line.replace('xx1001.', '')
```